# Can I get the parameter from inside the requested html in an HTTP GET Request URL?

Tags: javascript, html

When I attempt to load a html onto a page, I need to pass a parameter and use it inside the loaded html. However, I'm not sure how I would be able to access that that URL parameter.

[Here is how it should flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxdGA.png)

I need to utilize the parameter passed and change the HTML A content based on the parameter making it dynamic HTML.

Is this even possible?

**Technology info:**

1. Parent page setup - *URL: abc.com* - Application React-app placing html content in a container using -
   container.appendChild(range.createContextualFragment(this.state.html_a));
2. Load HTML from - hosted server  - *HTML URL: 123.com/html?value=html_a*

Note: cross-origin

Comment: provide more info on your set up: back-end, template engine if any.

Comment: Added additional info on tech setup